# How to install Java 8 on Kali Nethunter

Tags: linux, java, operating-systems, kali-linux

Guys I need to install jdk 8 for my programs to work better, many programs do not support the version higher than Java 8 so I want to install Java 8 to run better, I tried to install via `apt-get`, but I saw that it was removed from the Kali repository because very old. Can anyone help me how to install? When I run the command `uname -m` it shows me that the architecture is aarch64 can someone tell me how to install Java 8 on Nethunter for aarch64? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is definitely not a security question. Not sure where it belongs though? Kali is debian. Migrate this question to SuperUser? Unix&Linux?

Comment: I already asked this question on the super user, I'm going to do it on Unix & Linux I wasn't sure if I could put it there :)

Comment: Do not cross-post on StackExchange. Post once and let the communities move to a more appropriate site.